# Concrete Mathematics, The conditions of formula(5.12)

Tags: binomial-coefficients, absolute-convergence

I'm currently reading the book *Concrete Mathematics*, and I feel like I cannot understand the conditions author put on 5.12. The text is:

> $$(x + y)^r = \sum_k {r \choose k} x ^ ky^{r-k} $$$$\text{integer r} \ge \text{0 or }|x/y|\lt 1$$
>
> The sum is over all integers k; but it is really a nite sum when r is a nonnegative integer, because all terms are zero except those with $0 \le k \le r$. On the
> other hand, the theorem is also valid when r is negative, or even when r is
> an arbitrary real or complex number. In such cases the sum really is infinite,
> and we must have $|x/y|\lt 1$ to guarantee the sum's absolute convergence.
> Two special cases of the binomial theorem are worth special attention,
> even though they are extremely simple. If x = y = 1 and r = n is nonnegative,
> we get
> $$2^n = {n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} + \cdots+{n \choose n}, \text{integer } n \ge 0$$

I am confused with the $|x/y|\lt 1$ condition. I think it means "the absolute value of x/y", but how can $x=y=1$ be a case of the formula if $|x/y|\lt 1$? If id doesn't mean absolute value, what does it mean?

It's my first time using MathJax. Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: That's subsumed under the case $r$ is a nonnegative integer.

Comment: They're two separate sentences. "In such cases..." is one scenario. "If $x=y=1$..." is another.

Comment: Sean Roberson, sorry I didn't format very well, but 2 sentences you mentioned were originally 2 seperate paragraphs in the book. The second formula is a special case of the first, where x=y=1 and r=n. What I am confused with is that the conditions of the first formula wouldn't allow x=y=1 if "absolute value of x over y < 1".

Comment: If $r$ is a positive integer then the condition $|x/y|<1$ is not necessary because the stated binomial expansion is an identity, RHS has $r+1$ terms for all real values of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solves my problem and let me recognized what a careless question I have asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I made an careless mistake by ignoring the "or" between the two conditions. Since the first condition is satisfied, the second one don't need to be satisfied. Thank all of you for helping me on it.